# Remove duplicate element in object and leave unique element

Tags: javascript, object, lodash

I have two object:

**obj1**

```
{
  "uuid": "",
  "open_bal_qty": 0,
  "open_bal_value": 0,
  "qty_min": 0,
  "qty_med": 0,
  "qty_max": 0,
  "kedai_uuid": "198ceaef-4ced-4207-9ba0-62afbb42bb85"
}
```

**obj2**

```
{
  "uuid": "",
  "open_bal_qty": 0,
  "open_bal_value": 0,
  "kedai_uuid": "198ceaef-4ced-4207-9ba0-62afbb42bb85"
}
```

How can I remove duplicate and get element not exist in `obj2` so my new obj will be:

**newObj**

```
{
  "qty_min": 0,
  "qty_med": 0,
  "qty_max": 0,
}
```

I can use lodash `pick` but I dont want to manually entered the key name that I want to filter.

```
const newObj = pick(obj1, [
  'qty_min',
  'qty_med',
  'qty_max',
]);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could use `_.difference(array, [values])` on the keys for the two objects, and use that in your pick function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `for..in` to iterate the object and `Object.hasOwnProperty` to check if the second object have the same key

```js
var obj1 = {
  "uuid": "",
  "open_bal_qty": 0,
  "open_bal_value": 0,
  "qty_min": 0,
  "qty_med": 0,
  "qty_max": 0,
  "kedai_uuid": "198ceaef-4ced-4207-9ba0-62afbb42bb85"
}
var obj2 = {
  "uuid": "",
  "open_bal_qty": 0,
  "open_bal_value": 0,
  "kedai_uuid": "198ceaef-4ced-4207-9ba0-62afbb42bb85"
}
var newObj = {};
for (var keys in obj1) {
  if (!obj2.hasOwnProperty(keys)) {
    newObj[keys] = obj1[keys]
  }
}

console.log(newObj)
```

Comment: careful...doesn't work if obj2 has unique properties

Answer (score 2):

With lodash you can [`_.omit()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#omit) from `obj1` all the [`_.keys()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#keys) of `obj2`:

```js
const obj1 = {"uuid":"","open_bal_qty":0,"open_bal_value":0,"qty_min":0,"qty_med":0,"qty_max":0,"kedai_uuid":"198ceaef-4ced-4207-9ba0-62afbb42bb85"};

const obj2 = {"uuid":"","open_bal_qty":0,"open_bal_value":0,"kedai_uuid":"198ceaef-4ced-4207-9ba0-62afbb42bb85"};

const newObj = _.omit(obj1, _.keys(obj2));

console.log(newObj);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `_.pick` in conjunction with [`_.difference`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#difference) by finding the difference between the two objects' keys and picking those keys:

```js
const obj1 = {
  "uuid": "",
  "open_bal_qty": 0,
  "open_bal_value": 0,
  "qty_min": 0,
  "qty_med": 0,
  "qty_max": 0,
  "kedai_uuid": "198ceaef-4ced-4207-9ba0-62afbb42bb85"
};

const obj2 = {
  "uuid": "",
  "open_bal_qty": 0,
  "open_bal_value": 0,
  "kedai_uuid": "198ceaef-4ced-4207-9ba0-62afbb42bb85"
};

const obj1Keys = _.keys(obj1); //or Object.keys
const obj2Keys = _.keys(obj2);
console.log(_.pick(obj1Keys > obj2Keys ? obj1 : obj2, _.difference(obj1Keys, obj2Keys)))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.js"></script>
```